# Flood fill on 2d grid

Tags: python, flood-fill

As part of a game, I am building a 2d grid where I need to find out if two items on the grid are connected. There are e.g. traps and walls that are blocking the way so basically I end up with separate parts of the grid divided by the walls and traps, so I'm flood filling the grid starting from a point P on the grid to find out which points belong to the same part with P.

Here's what the code basically does:

1) build the grid based on an input file (works)

2) find the starting point P (works)

3) flood fill from P (DOES NOT WORK)

4) print the grid to check if it's right (works)

The grid is built just fine, and the starting point is found as well, but the flood fill function does not work. Any ideas?

Example input file:

```
7 9
#######
#..#G.#
#...TG#
#.....#
#...G.#
#...#.#
###.P.#
#G#.TG#
#######
```

(UPDATED, works ok now) Running the code with that prints the following:

```
Start point at: [4, 6] (i.e. in grid[6][4])
[0, '#'][2, '#'][2, '#'][0, '#'][2, '#'][2, '#'][0, '#']
[2, '#'][1, '.'][1, '.'][2, '#'][1, 'G'][1, '.'][2, '#']
[2, '#'][1, '.'][1, '.'][1, '.'][2, 'T'][1, 'G'][2, '#']
[2, '#'][1, '.'][1, '.'][1, '.'][1, '.'][1, '.'][2, '#']
[2, '#'][1, '.'][1, '.'][1, '.'][1, 'G'][1, '.'][2, '#']
[2, '#'][1, '.'][1, '.'][1, '.'][2, '#'][1, '.'][2, '#']
[0, '#'][2, '#'][2, '#'][1, '.'][1, 'P'][1, '.'][2, '#']
[0, '#'][0, 'G'][2, '#'][1, '.'][2, 'T'][1, 'G'][2, '#']
[0, '#'][0, '#'][0, '#'][2, '#'][0, '#'][2, '#'][0, '#']
```

(UPDATED, works fine) And here's the code itself:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

  class Node:
    UNEXPLORED = 0
    CONNECTED = 1
    VISITED = 2

    def __init__(self, x, y, value):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.state = Node.UNEXPLORED
      self.value = value

    def neighbor_with(self, node):
      x_dist = abs(self.x - node.x)
      y_dist = abs(self.y - node.y)
      if x_dist == 1 and y_dist == 0:
        return True
      elif x_dist == 0 and y_dist == 1:
        return True
      else:
        return False

    def trap_or_wall(self):
      if self.value == "T" or self.value == "#":
        return True
      else:
        return False

    def __str__(self):
      return str([self.state,self.value])



  with open('in1.txt', 'r') as f:

    row = f.readline()
    dimensions = row.split(" ")
    w = int(dimensions[0])
    h = int(dimensions[1])

    grid = [[Node(j,i, None) for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]

    #set grid
    for i in range(h):
      row = f.readline()
      for j in range(w):
        grid[i][j].value = row[j]

    #find P
    p = []
    for i in range(h):
      for j in range(w):
        if grid[i][j].value == "P":
          p = [grid[i][j].y, grid[i][j].x]
    print("Start point at: {:} (i.e. in grid[{:}][{:}])".format(p,p[1],p[0]))

    #define function to flood fill the connected part
    def fill_connected(matrix, node):
      if node.state == Node.UNEXPLORED:
        node.state = Node.VISITED
        if not node.trap_or_wall():
          node.state = Node.CONNECTED
          #recursively for neighbors
          for i in range(h):
            for j in range(w):
              if matrix[i][j].neighbor_with(node):
                fill_connected(matrix, grid[i][j])

    #flood fill from P
    fill_connected(grid, grid[p[1]][p[0]])

    #check grid, i.e. print it
    for i in range(h):
      for j in range(w):
        print(grid[i][j], end="")
      print("\n", end="")
    print()
```

**EDIT:**

I updated the code to account for the mistakes in the order of coordinates, x=4 and y=6 should now be grid[6][4]. I fixed the other errors after that then, but I still do not understand one thing: in the last line of the flood fill function definition, why does it have to be grid[i][j] instead of grid[j][i]? The latter one produces an out of range error.

Answer (score 2):

You mess up with the order of coordinates. You use grid(Y, X) almost everywhere, except for the fill function. See the initial call: you find the P at x=4 y=6 which is i=6  j=4. And then you call fill_connected(4,6). This is a point in the right wall.

I would work on list indices only, if there is no good reason for extra coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for the notion, I did mess up those. I have updated the code to (hopefully) be correct in that sense now. But I get an out of range error now, would you mind taking another look at the updated code? Thanks.

Comment: I swapped indeces on one line (the recursive call of fill_connected), and it works now. But why does it have to be the opposite there unlike elsewhere? It is grid[y][x] there now when it works.

Comment: Hi! First of all, you have ALWAYS grid[heightIndex][widthIndex] and in this context, i always stands for heightIndex and j for widthIndex. When writing "grid = [[Node(i,j, None)...", you assigned i (height) to x(width) etc, and that was your problem. Now, you have written "grid = [[Node(j,i, None)..." which makes xy the same as ij. Because of this, you run into trouble again with p[].

Comment: As second comment, to separate it: The old code, calling fill_connected() four times with x, y +/-1 was much more elegant. Also, defining functions within other code is not so nice.
And as last suggestion, as said before: I would forget about x and y and ONLY work on i and j.